# [AWS CodeBuild]The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.0.0". Got "10.19.0"

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to deploy my React application through AWS codepipeline and codebuild.

However, codebuild failed with below error:

```
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:19 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:29 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:30 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:30 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src234015054/src
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:30 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src234015054/src/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:30 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:30 [WARN] Skipping install of runtimes. Runtime version selection is not supported by this build image.
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src234015054/src
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Expanded cache path ./node_modules/**/*
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Configuring ssm agent with target id: codebuild:0a77403f-035c-4d62-b96e-de5449f7f4bc
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Successfully updated ssm agent configuration
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Registering with agent
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Phases found in YAML: 2
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33  INSTALL: 2 commands
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33  BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Running command echo Performing yarn install
Performing yarn install

[Container] 2022/04/19 02:42:33 Running command yarn install
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/5] Validating package.json...
error website@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.0.0". Got "10.19.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I don't know why codebuild picked `10.19.0` here.

#### More Info

I'm using `yarn build` to build package. I can run the app with `yarn start` without problem locally.

Here is my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
    commands:
      - echo Performing yarn install
      - yarn install
  build:
    commands:
      - yarn build

artifacts:
  base-directory: ./build
  files:
    - "**/*"

cache:
  paths:
    - "./node_modules/**/*"
```

I also specified the node version in `package.json`:

```
 "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0",
    "npm": ">=8.5.5"
  },
```

#### Update With Solution

I'm able to solve the issue based on fedonev@'s answer.

As he said, I need configure the build image to use `CodeBuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0` in CodeBuild Project.

```js
// AWS CodePipeline stage to build website
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: "Build",
  actions: [
    // AWS CodePipeline action to run CodeBuild project
    new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: "BuildeWebsite",
      project: new CodeBuild.PipelineProject(this, "BuildWebsite", {
        projectName: "BuildeWebsite",
        environment: {
          buildImage: CodeBuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0
        },
        buildSpec:
          CodeBuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename("./buildspec.yml"),
      }),
      input: outputSources,
      outputs: [outputWebsite],
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also configure the CodeBuild Project to use a [build image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) that [supports the Nodejs v14 runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html). The Ubuntu Standard 5 image is the only image that does at the moment.  In CloudFormation:

```yaml
Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
Properties: 
  Environment:
    Image: "aws/codebuild/standard:5.0"
```